# For given system of ODE's, in a region $\Omega$ in the $uw$-plane, show it's a trapping region for large R

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology

Need help figuring out what this question wants me to do. No need to do entire problem for me, just need a push in the right direction on how to solve

Here's my system:
\begin{gather*} 
    \frac{du}{dt}=u(1-u^2)-w \\ 
    \frac{dw}{dt}=u
\end{gather*}

Consider region $\Omega$ in $uw$-plane, and show that it is a trapping region for sufficiently large R.

[image]

Update: So I've come to the conclusion that this is way to go,

AB: $u=-R, w=0$ $\implies \frac{du}{dt}|_{(-R,0)}=-R(1-R^2)$ and $\frac{dw}{dt}|_{(-R,0)}=-R<0$. Here if $|R|<1$ then $\frac{du}{dt}|_{(-R,0)}=-R(1-R^2)<0$ and $\frac{du}{dt}|_{(-R,0)}=-R(1-R^2)>0$ otherwise

BC: $u=R, w=R$ $\implies\frac{du}{dt}|_{(R,R)}=-R^3<0$ and $\frac{dw}{dt}|_{(R,R)}=R>0$

CD: $u=0, w=-R$ $\implies\frac{du}{dt}|_{(0,-R)}=R>0$ and $\frac{dw}{dt}|_{(0,-R)}=0$

so on and so forth for each grid section...

Is my intuition on how to do this make sense?

Comment: A trapping region is a region that if your system starts within, it will always stay within.  I think you could prove that the above region is a trapping region by showing the derivatives on the boundary point inwards.

Comment: a limit cycle perhaps?

Comment: This is one of the first-order formulations of the van der Pol oscillator. Take the derivative of the first equation to get $u''+(3u^2-1)u'+u=0$ or with $x=\sqrt3u$ the standard form $x''+(x^2-1)x'+x=0$. It is well-known that this last equation has a limit cycle in the vicinity of the circle of radius $2$.

Comment: Can I apply the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem even though it has a steady state point at the origin? Would it satisfy it otherwise?

Comment: Would it benefit to convert $\frac{du}{dt}=u(1-u^2)-w$ and $\frac{dw}{dt}=u$ into $\frac{du}{dw}=(1-u^2)-w/u$

Answer (score 1):

**On AB:** You have $w=R$ and $u\in[-R,0]$. An outward pointing vector is  $(0,1)$. The component of the vector field in that direction is $u\le 0$, thus it points inwards, or at least not outwards.

**On BC:** $u+w=R$, $u\in[0,R]$. The vector $(1,1)$ points outwards. The scalar product with the vector field is
$$
u(1-u^2)-w+u=3u-u^3-R.
$$
$3u-u^3$ has a maximum for positive $u$ at $u=1$ with value $2$. Thus for $R>2$ the vector field is pointing inwards on this segment.

**On CD:** $u=R$, $w\in[-R,0]$. An outwards pointing vector is $(1,0)$. The component of the vector field in that direction is $R(1-R^2)-w$. This is maximal for $w=-R$ with value $2R-R^3=R(2-R^2)$. For $R>2$ this is negative.

The other segments are point-symmetric (at the origin) to previous segments.